Learning Sanskrit through translated ancient texts for beginner
I dislike the current way information on Sanskrit Grammar is presented. I am wondering if there are good summary books on medieval texts to teach kids Sanskrit from the absolute basics translated into English. Other than that any good dictionaries by medieval scholars translated?
